# How declare Ajax functions ussing SHORTINIT

Tags: ajax

I try to use `SHORTINIT` in my wordpress to do Ajax more fast, but I try to declare my functions and don't return any value.

My code is:

```
define('SHORTINIT',true);
require_once ('../../../../wp-load.php');
require_once ('../../../../wp-config.php');

function muestraMensaje_callback(){
    echo "hola que tal";
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_muestraMensaje', 'muestraMensaje_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_muestraMensaje', 'muestraMensaje_callback');
```

And in my functions I've this code:

```
/*
 *  Ajaxs function
 */
add_action('init','registraAjax');
function registraAjax(){
    wp_register_script('miScript', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/js/ajax.js');
    //$miUrl=array('url'=>admin_url('admin-ajax.php'));
    $miUrl=array('url'=>get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/myAjax/ajax.php');
    wp_localize_script(miScript, 'MyAjax', $miUrl);
    wp_enqueue_script('miScript',get_bloginfo('stylessheet_directory').'/js/ajax.js');
}
```

What can be the problem? If I called to my `muestraMensaje` I didn't have any value.

**Edit:**

Now I've a new problem: give me the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function main() on a non-object...line
>   873

I looking for the solution but everybody said this error is for not include **wp-load.php** but I've include this file....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build the PHP script that will handle the ajax resquest and send the ajax request directly to that filet (not to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php). In that file, first define `SHORTINIT`, then load WordPress manually and finally handle the ajax request.

```
define('SHORTINIT',true);
//IMPORTANT: Change with the correct path to wp-load.php in your installation
require_once ('../../../../wp-load.php');
//Load any WordPress module you may need from the include folder
//For exmaple:
//require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/meta.php' );
//require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/post.php' );

muestraMensaje();

function muestraMensaje(){
    echo "hola que tal";
    die();
}
```

Suppose you have named that file ajax.php and that it is in located in the URL mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/a-plugin/ajax.php. The, the javascript should be something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/a-plugin/ajax.php",
})
.done(function( data ) {
    alert(data);
});
```

In the next example I use these WordPress functions: `upadate_post_meta`, `get_post_custom`, `wp_send_json_success` and `wp_send_json_error`. This modules are needed:

- load.php: always needed to load WordPress
- formatting.php: it contains sanitizing functions used by `upadate_post_meta`
- meta.php: it contains functions related with post meta data and custom fields
- post.php and revision.php: these modules contains post related functions needed when updating post data.

So, this is the PHP script:

```
define('SHORTINIT', true);
//IMPORTANT: Change with the correct path to wp-load.php in your installation
require( '../../../wp-load.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/formatting.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/meta.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/post.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/revision.php' );

cyb_uptdate_hits();

function cyb_uptdate_hits(){

    if( isset($_GET['postID']) ) {

        $post_id = intval( $_GET['postID']);

        if( $post_id > 0 ) {

            $get_meta = get_post_custom($post_id);

            if( isset($get_meta['hits'][0]) ) {
                $prev = intval($get_meta['hits'][0]);
            } else {
                $prev = 0;
            }

            update_post_meta($post_id, 'hits', $prev + 1);
            $res = array('postID' => $post_id, 'hits' => $prev + 1);
            wp_send_json_success($res);

        } else {
            wp_send_json_error('No post to update.');
        }

    } else {
        wp_send_json_error('No post to update.');
    }

    die('You die!');

}
```

This is the javascript I'm using:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Update post hits counter
        if( typeof cyb_hits_data.postID !== 'undefined' && cyb_hits_data.postID != "0") {
            var update_hits = function(post_id){
                $.getJSON(cyb_hits_data.ajax_url,{
                    postID : post_id
                });
            }
            update_hits(cyb_hits_data.postID);
        }

    });
})(jQuery);
```

And the enqueue javascript:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cyb_hits_enqueue_scripts' );
function cyb_hits_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('cyb-hits', plugins_url( '/js/hits.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('cyb-hits');

    $theID = 0;
    if(is_single()) {
        $theID = get_the_ID();
    }

    $scriptData = array(
                  'ajax_url' => plugins_url( '/ajax_hits.php', __FILE__ ),
                  'postID'  => $theID
                );
    wp_localize_script('cyb-hits','cyb_hits_data',$scriptData);



}
```

Comment: THanks! @cybmeta. Now I've the error: call to a member function main() but all said is the wp-load.php buy I include in my folder

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "but all said is the wp-load.php buy I include in my folder". Can you try to explain better? The code I posted is working, if you have modified it, please tell me. Note hat, as said in the answer, when using `SHORTINIT` WordPress is loaded with the minimum that is required and you have to include the modules you need manually. If you try to use functions that are not loaded you will get errors. I can not know what modules you need; I've added a working example that I'm using on a live site.

Comment: Sorry @cybmeta : I sais this because I load the file wp-load.php in my ajax.php. I looking for the solution to my problem "Call to a member function main()...." but I always found the solution is load the wp-load.php file but I 've this in my ajax.php like this: include_once ('../../../../wp-load.php'); and always have the same error

Comment: Check that the path to wp-load.php is correct. I can not know where your ajax.php is located if don't tell me, if you say to me the location of ajax.php, I can say to you the correct path to wp-load.php to be included in ajax.php. Also, I recommend to not use `inclue_once` to load wp-load.php, use `require_once` insteaad as I post in the answer; this way you will be sure that the script will stop executing if the loading fails.

Comment: I think is correct because if I change the path I've error like failed to open stream, ABSPATH is not declare...

Comment: It is obvious to me that you have modified the code: you are using `include_once` instead of `require_once` that is in the answer code. Please, if you have modified the code I posted you must tell me. Otherwise I can not help you. The code I posted is working and should be market as accepted answer. Your problem now is another one. Mixing problems will confuse future users.

Comment: Ok, I check like answer you comment and open other question ;) thanks @cybmeta

Comment: Also, if you post the full code you are using, including the modifications you have done to the answer code, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Yes yes, I will put this (is the same code but I changed the include_once for the require_once again) But, to make more clear, I think is better open a new question @cybmeta

Comment: Sorry to comment again. I think your problem is "where" you are inserting the PHP code. Are you creating a separate PHP file as said in the answer or are you pasting the code in a existent file?

Comment: I put this code in my-ajax.php (all my ajax's functions) file and in my ajax.js (this file made the ajax call) @cybmeta