# Error function main() is a non-object to construct my Ajax.php

Tags: functions, ajax

Try to use a "rapid" ajax, I've the follow code in my my-ajax.php file

```
define('SHORTINIT',true);
require_once ('../../../../wp-load.php');
require_once ('../../../../wp-config.php');
require_once ('../../../../wp-blog-header.php');
if ((!isset($_POST["action"])) || ($_POST["action"]!=="") || (!is_numeric($_POST["action"]))) {
    switch($_POST["action"]){
        case 'buscaPost':
            if ((isset($_POST["miPost"])) || (isset($_POST["slug"]))){
                echo "my actions";
                die();
            }else{
                echo "Fail!";
            }
            break;
    }   
}
```

I try to change the values of wp-load.php path but this is the correct path.

My file my-ajax.php is in

```
/www/wp-conent/themes/myTheme/folderTheme/myAjax/my-ajax.php
```

Edit:

I'm not sure if this is the correct way but I need WP_Query to use this in my ajax and now I include the follow requires:

```
require_once ('../../../../wp-load.php');
require_once ('../../../../wp-includes/taxonomy.php');
require_once ('../../../../wp-includes/meta.php');
require_once ('../../../../wp-includes/pluggable.php');
require_once ('../../../../wp-includes/post.php');
require_once ('../../../../wp-includes/query.php');
```

But I've the error

```
get_current_user_id() is not defined
```

This is include in the wp-includes/pluggable.php.
Maybe exists other way to add this wordpress object (WP_Query)??

Now I've other problems with AUTH_COOKIE, LOGGED_IN_COOKIE (this constants are not defined) and call_user_func_array (this said: expect parameter 1 to be a valid callback).

My code actually is:

```
define('SHORTINIT',true);
define('AUTH_COOKIE',true);
define('LOGGED_IN_COOKIE',true);
// I add this define to correct the error who send me Wordpress, he said this constants are not defined
require_once ('../../../../wp-load.php');
require_once ('../../../../wp-includes/taxonomy.php');
require_once ('../../../../wp-includes/meta.php');
require_once ('../../../../wp-includes/post.php');
require_once ('../../../../wp-includes/user.php');
require_once ('../../../../wp-includes/pluggable.php');
require_once ('../../../../wp-includes/capabilities.php');
require_once ('../../../../wp-includes/query.php');
require_once ('ajax-funciones.php'); //some functions to returns values, actually only return "hi everybody".
if ((!isset($_POST["action"])) || ($_POST["action"]!=="") || (!is_numeric($_POST["action"]))) {
    switch($_POST["action"]){
        case 'buscaPost':
            if ((isset($_POST["miPost"])) || (isset($_POST["slug"]))){
                sacaPost($_POST["miPost"],$_POST["slug"]);
                die();
            }else{
                echo "No hay variables";
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

What can be the mistake?

Other problem is: I've been put a function in my ajax-funciones.php like this:

```
function sacaPost($idPost,$slugPost){   
    // Buscamos el contenido del post
    $query = array("cat"=>$_POST["miPost"]);    
    $objetoDatos = new WP_Query($query);    
    if ($objetoDatos->have_posts()){
        while($objetoDatos->have_posts()){
            $objetoDatos->the_post();
            the_content();              
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }else{
        echo "any";
    }   
}
```

And called this in my-ajax.php but always return "any" and I don't know the reason. It's necesary other way to rescue the values?

Comment: Loading `wp-config.php` and `wp-blog-header.php` is not needed if you load `wp-load.php`. If you see `wp-blog-header.php` file content, you will see that this file loads `wp-load.php` and `wp-template-loader.php`. If you don't need the template engine of WordPress load only `wp-load.php`. `wp-config.php` is loaded in `wp-load.php` also, you don't to load it manually.

Comment: By the way, this code is not the one I gave you in [the other question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173002/how-declare-ajax-functions-ussing-shortinit/173006) but you said, more than once, that you had not modified it. Please, for future questions, be honest. We are here spending our free time trying to help and if we have incorrect information we can not do it and waste a lot of time for nothing.

Comment: I confirm that loading `wp-load-php`, `wp-config.php` and `wp-blog-loader.php` at the same time generate the error. Remember that, as I said before, `wp-config.php` is loaded in `wp-load.php` and that `wp-blog-header.php` is loading again `wp-load.php`. Use only `wp-load.php` or, if you need the template engine, use only `wp-blog-header.php`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I made the changes in the other question but I've some problems in my conexion and I forget see if the question has been edited (I saw your answers in my mobile and I didn't see the question again)

Comment: I add others requires in my ajax (I put this in the question) but I'm not sure if this is the correct way @cybmeta

Comment: To use user related functions you must include `wp-includes/user.php`. Every time you get errors like that, try to read the documentation to see where the function is located. For example, in the case of `get_current_user_id()`, which is your problem now, it is located in `wp-includes/user.php` and [that info is in the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id#Source_Code).

Comment: Yes, but for example, now Wordpress said: AUTH_COOKIE and LOGGED_IN_COOKIE is not defined and one error in a call_user_func_array (this said expect parameter 1 to be a valid callback). I ussing 8 requires in my ajax.php

Comment: I'm sorry but I can not continue to help you. You have one error, then modify the code and come with another, then modifiy the code and come with another one, this seems a endless sitaution that may need a custom job involved. Also, note that all errors in this thread are generic PHP errors and generic PHP errors are off-topic on WPSE.